# Why is my shadow layer not positioned correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, shadow

I got a custom subclass of `UIView` called `RoundedView`:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundedView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor : UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
            layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset : CGSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20) {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
            layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius : CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
            layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity : Float = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
            layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        }
    }


}
```

With this class, I want to be able to set the shadow for a view by using the Xcode Interface Builder.
Unfortunately, the behavior is pretty strange; when setting the color to blue, the offset to `CGSize.zero`, the radius to 0 and the opacity to 1, the whole shadow is moved to the right:

[image]

This is the output of 1. the shadowPath, 2. the bounds and 3. the frame:

```
shadowPath: 
    Path 0x60800022e040:
      moveto (0, 0)
        lineto (300, 0)
        lineto (300, 150)
        lineto (0, 150)
        closepath
self.bounds: 
    (0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 150.0)
self.frame: 
    (37.0, 268.5, 300.0, 150.0)
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Could you help me out?

Comment: Try to set clipToBounds as true.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper That doesn't help, the shadow is hidden if I set clipToBounds. Also, it worked with the other views without setting clipsToBounds to true.

Comment: Set some value for `layer.shadowRadius`. It could not to be zero.

Comment: @SeyedSamadGholamzadeh I tried, no result. I think it can be zero, it worked with a normal view.

Comment: Oh you used `shadowPath`. I think thats the point. Because when you scrolling your view position changes but the shadowPath is constant.
Try to add `layer.shouldRasterize = true` after the `layer.shadowPath` you write and check if this corrects your problem?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot simply put this line

```
layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
```

into every didSet observer as the frame may still change.

Solved by overriding the function `layoutSubviews` and adding the line there.